# I'm following Qt Tutorials and got a simple question

Tags: qt, constructor, qt4

If I want to create my own class MyWidget which inherits from QWidget

Tutorial tells me to write constructor like this...

```
MyWidget::MyWidget(QWidget *parent)
: QWidget(parent){....}
```

I'm wondering what is the role of : QWidget(parent)

Does it mean explicit call for QWidget's constructor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  In C++, if you must explicitly call the base class's constructor in your constructor's [initialization list](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html) if you want it to run.  In this case, `QWidget(parent)` would be run before running the code in your constructor.  By the way, this is not just a Qt thing, but is common in C++ inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the previous answer:

1 Like it was mentioned if parent not null you widget will be rendered just inside parent widget.

2 If parent widget is deleted you all his child widgets will be also deleted by delete operator.

Correct implementation of default widget constructor should be the following:

```
class MyWidget: public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        explicit MyWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
}

MyWidget::MyWidget(QWidget *parent = 0): QWidget(parent) {
    // Your own initialization code
}
```

Try to avoid specifing nonzero parent for stack widget. You'd better always create nested widget in the way:

```
QWidget *parentWidget;
MyWidget myWidget = new MyWidget(parentWidget);
```

You can read more here:
http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/objecttrees.html

Answer (score 0):

From [**"yours"**](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.3/tutorial-t4.html) Qt tutorial: *Because this class inherits from QWidget, the new class is a widget and may be a top-level window or a child widget (like the QPushButton in the previous chapter)*.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

That is called an initialization list in C++, and yes, it's an explicit call to QWidget's constructor. By default C++ calls the no-argument version of its base classes' constructors, unless there is an explicit call in the initialization list. It is generally considered good design that the initialization of members of a class are handled by that class's constructor - Qt follows this convention. So, here you are passing a pointer to its base class's constructor, so it can store it in one of its member variables.